# Scala dynamic tuple type construction from sequence

Tags: scala, types

I'm trying to generate some json using the [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) library which builds json using a dsl based around nested tuple structures. I have a scala `Seq` that I'd like to be able to convert to a nesting of tuples like so:

```
// scala Seq
val s = Seq("a", "b", "c", "d")
val rootItem = "id" -> 1234
// desired json
{
  "a" : {
    "b" : {
      "c" : {
        "d" : {
          "id" : 1234
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I force it to ignore the types I can produce the desired tuple structure as follows:

```
// yields ("a", ("b", ("c", ("d", ("id", 1234)))))
s.foldRight[Any](rootItem)(_ -> _)
```

but because the type of the result is now denoted as `Any` the implicit conversion that write this to json don't fire (and throw an exception when called explicitly) despite the actual type being correct. I'm at a loss for how to construct this datastructure in a typesafe way. Ideally I'd like a solution that is able to appropriately build up the type, though I understand that it might be impossible since it requires information only available at runtime (the length of the list). I know that scala supports recursive types, which seem to potentially fit the bill but I haven't been able to understand how to work them in this case and don't know if they are safe for a 'real' system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do this with a plain old fold, since the accumulator has to be the same type the whole time.

You can make the transformation to JSON as you go, however:

```
val s = Seq("a", "b", "c", "d")
val rootItem = "id" -> 1234

import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

val json = s.foldRight[JObject](rootItem)(_ -> _)
```

And then you can do the following, since `json` is statically typed as a `JObject`:

```
scala> pretty(render(json))
res0: String = 
{
  "a" : {
    "b" : {
      "c" : {
        "d" : {
          "id" : 1234
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(As a footnote, there is [a way](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) you could do the fold with tuples and end up with the appropriate static type, but that's almost certainly not what you want in this case.)

Comment: Beautiful, this is just what I wanted and far simpler than I had feared.